# From where the deleteconfirmed action get the Id in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Maybe the question was already asked but never answered!!

How the deleteconfirmed method get the id by the post method ?

- There is no hidden fields containing the Id .
- I tampered data to change the referer Url so that it not contains the id anymore but the deleteconfirmed action still get the correct id passed during the get .

Then from where does it come ?

here is the code , the get method :

```
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        Driver driver= db.Drivers.Find(id);
        if (driver== null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(driver);
    }


    // POST: /Driver/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {

        Driver driver= db.drivers.Find(id);
        db.drivers.Remove(driver);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: What "deleteconfirmed" method? Share some code so we can figure out what you are refering to.

Comment: I checked RouteData dictionnary and it contains the id , so this is from where it comes , but the question is how is it possible while i tampered data and changed referrer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Html.BeginForm()` helper will add route parameters to the forms `action` action attribute based your route definitions in `RouteConfig.cs`

Assuming you have the default route `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",` then if you pass a value to (say) 5 to the `Delete(int? id)` get method, then if you inspect the form tag you will see `<form action="/YourController/Delete/5" ...>`. Note this will also be added if the model you pass to the view has a property named `id`.

When you post the form, the `DefaultModelBinder` read the values of form fields (`Request.Form`), but also values from route data and query string parameters, so even though you do not have a hidden input for `id`, it is set from the route parameters.

Comment: Thank's lot for your answer i was aware of all what you said except checking the form tag , i thought that the id was passed in complex way that cannot be changed , in the default template the id is not optional and changing action in the form tag lead to server error ...                      thank's again for your answer !